# MEF: How to retrieve a new instance for a type?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Within my class I have a class that imports a type like this:

```
[Import]
public ContactViewModel ContactViewModel { get; set; }
```

The type is defined like this:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[Export(typeof(ContactViewModel))]
public class ContactViewModel {}
```

I am expecting whenever I would read from the property, to get a new instance right?
Or maybe not...I keep getting the same instance, how do I force t to make me a new instance when using the property?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you are recomposing your consumer class? The `NonShared` creation policy will ensure that a new instance is created each time the part is required to compose, so I would check the other side of it, which is the class where you are `[Import]`-ing your part. Is that class being recomposed correctly?

Your other option is to use an `ExportFactory`, e.g.:

```
[Import] public ExportFactory<ContactViewModel> ViewModelFactory { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, no the class owning the property above is a controller (Shared) class, hence it should not be recomposed.  I think the factory is the solution. Let me try it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! So this is like in Unity when doing _container.Resolve<viewmodel>(); correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a factory and export that instead and then use it as your property. MEF part creation policy applies to when MEF is constructing the object which has dependency not when those dependencies are accessed.